# USB Connect: Unknown Error. On Ubuntu 19.04 Guest in a Windows 10 host

Tags: windows, usb, vmware-workstation

I set to automatic connect USB devices and it doesn't work. I also re-installed VMware tools and nothing. The USB doesn't connect and if I right click and select 'Connect (disconnect from host)' I always get this Unknown error message. 
Really annoying, a day lost with this.

[image]

Comment: Not all USB devices can be used. Which one in particular are you trying to use?

Comment: a hardware wallet

Comment: Crypto? Nice, I wish I had one of those... Did you installed software/drivers in the host? It may hijack it (AKA "in use") and not let it connect with the VM. This always implies "detaching" it from the host. But this is just a guess.